# include dot(.) and hyphen(-) in a regex

Tags: php, regex

```
 if(preg_match('/[^a-z\-0-9]/i', $value))

    {
    echo "<META HTTP-EQUIV='Refresh' Content='0; URL=http://$ponka/name/error'>";
}
```

how to include a dot and hyphen in the above code?
I know how to add dot or hyphen in the code which is if-yes-then-if-then-else. This code is if-no-then-if-then-else (if you got what I am trying to say)

Comment: @confusedmammal, your question is not very clear. You may benefit from reading http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for some guidelines on asking good questions. The key thing is to simplify the question to it's simplest form - you're asking about php regex, and you want your regex to match dot and hyphen also (or something like that, right?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `hyphen` **doesn't** need to be escaped if it's the **first** or **last** in the character class.
The `dot` also **doesn't** need to escaped when used inside a character class `[]` i.e.:

```
/[^a-z.0-9-]/i
```

---

**NOTES:**

Apart from the above, the meta characters that also need to be escaped inside a character class are:

```
^ (negation)
- (range)
] (end of the class)
\ (escape char)
```

Comment: I have clarified my own answer to be in the group rather than the overall argument.

Answer (score 1):

The hyphen is already in there, simply add an escaped dot using `\.`.

/edit: But as noted in the comment the escaping isn't needed.

Comment: The `.` doesn't need to be escaped in a character class.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are talking about the regex, you escape both with a slash `\`.

```
/[^a-z\.\-0-9]/i
```

Answer (score -1):

The hyphen does not need to be escaped if it is the *last* character in the Regex group. But the dot should always be escaped, so

```
'/[^a-z\.0-9-]/i'
```

Will check for **a to z**, **.** , **0 to 9** and **-** in that order, case insensitively.

Comment: The `.` doesn't need to be escaped in a character class. `In most regex flavors, the only special characters or metacharacters inside a character class are the closing bracket (]), the backslash (\), the caret (^), and the hyphen (-).` - http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html